# How to make an <input> the actual size of size="..."?

Tags: html, css

The size of an input field can be controlled

```html
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2">
```

The actual box is, however, wider than the selected width:

[image]

**How to make it the size selected in `size="..."`?**

I checked the calculated size in Chrome DevTools and the size is forced by the actual content (`12` in the example above), not some padding or other CSS-dependent modifications of size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size tells you how many characters can be entered. The width of the input box itself can be set through CSS.

```css
input {
width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2">
```